# Field Internal name changing when added to list?

Tags: content-type, column, online

I am having a very strange issue with the internal name of a site column. I created the column, added it to a Content Type, then created a list based on that content type.

Somewhere along the way SharePoint decided to give the field in the list a different Internal name than the actual site column. So If I look at the field settings from within the list, the field internal name is given as _x0050_AR612, while if I look a the column settings from the site content type, it is PAR612 (what I originally named it). The GUIDs are the same in either case, so I am sure it is talking about the same column.

This seems to be causing a conflict with the client side web part I am developing. If I try and write a new entry to the list including this field the write fails, no matter which form of the name form I use. Remove that field from the data object and the item gets created without issue.

Anyone else come across this? Ever find a solution? I have already tried destroying the column and re-creating it, but the same thing happens.

[image]

Comment: "I created the column, added it to a Content Type, then created a list based on that content type."

Are you doing the above from Browser? or via Code - PowerShell or Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

It appears SharePoint automatically does this if the column name has less than 4 characters followed by a number. If it was just PAR it would be fine or if it was PARX612 it would be fine. You could try creating the column with a different name and then renaming it after with the suitable display name.

Comment: Just faced the same issue. Thank you for the information. It helped. Couldn't find this anywhere on MSDN.